# count events within N days of first occurrence

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate

I have a series of rows in a table (pageviews of various articles) with columns for URL and timestamps, and I would like to see the total number of pageviews for each article within N days of its first pageview.

I can use "GROUP BY url" to view the total pageviews on each article, and I can use a WHERE clause to only count pageviews within a certain hard-coded date range, but I need to customize that date range for each unique URL.

I believe that I can use MIN() to find the first occurrence of each URL, but I need to somehow use those MIN() values together with a WHERE clause. I think I need to use a JOIN, but I can't seem to figure out that syntax. Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share the `table structure`, the query that you have attempted and expected result set. It might not be possible to construct an efficient query just by going through the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost exactly as you've explained it.

A version with a `JOIN`

```sql
SELECT v.url, COUNT(*) views
  FROM pageviews v JOIN (
    SELECT url, MIN(viewed_at) first_viewed_at
      FROM pageviews
     GROUP BY url
  ) f
   ON v.url = f.url
 WHERE v.viewed_at < f.first_viewed_at + INTERVAL 3 DAY
 GROUP BY v.url;
```

A version with a correlated subquery

```sql
SELECT url, COUNT(*) views
  FROM pageviews v
 WHERE viewed_at < (
   SELECT MIN(viewed_at)
     FROM pageviews
    WHERE url = v.url
   ) + INTERVAL 3 DAY
GROUP BY v.url;
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b3b0e9762a9c07025539c8d406d746b2) demo

Comment: Great, thank you! I'm querying Redshift via Redash, and it gave a syntax error on "+ INTERVAL 3 DAY". I tried just "+ 3" and that seems to be working fine.

Comment: You should've mentioned redshift in the first place. `+3` should work or you can explicitly use `DATEADD(day, 3, f.first_viewed_at)`